# Wordpress redirect in htacess not working

Tags: wordpress, apache

I know there is many questions like this, but i’ve been trying this for over 3 days now and still no success. 
I have wordpress site which i want to redirect entirnely to another site besides one url:     `www.oldsite.com/adv`

If i setup normal redirect for entire site it works but when I try to excluce certain folder from redirecting it refuses to work.

I have tried following code in my htacess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/adv
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L].
```

but this redirects all pages from oldsite including `oldsite.com/adv`

also I have tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/my-folder/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but this one gives 500 error.

do you have an idea what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^adv - [L,NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It will match any URI beginning adv.

- The - means do nothing.
- The L means this should be last rule; ignore everything following.
- The NC means no-case (so "ADV" is also matched).